# Sometimes duplicate strings come from android sqlite database

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have an sqlite database that I populate in a java program (I add the locale manually so it can be used with Android). Each entry in the database is essentially a sentence more or less, and I add all the sentences up to make a chapter.

**The Problem:** Sometimes, (so far this has only been identified on 2 Ice Cream Sandwich phones) I'm seeing part of the sentence written, then a line break, and then duplication of part of the sentence. I parse the sentences with a rather huge algorithm after getting them from the database, but this doesn't seem to be the issue, as after I unload the application (destroying cache), and re-load the same chapter the issue is gone. The variance seems to be coming from what I'm getting from the database.

**An example of what the user sees:**

> The small boy has received a gift to give
>   **line break is here for some reason**
>   boy has received a gift to give to his little sister as a birthday present.

**Some potentially weird things:** The database has a 3 column PK between sentence_num (unique number for each sentence in a chapter), book_name, chapter_num.

**Code I use to access Database**

```
    public synchronized List<ChapterElement> getSentenceChapter(SentenceReference sentenceRef) {
        Book book = sentenceRef.getBook();
        Integer chapter = sentenceRef.getChapter();

        String[] columns = {
                SentenceDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_SENTENCE_NUM,
                SentenceDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_SENTENCE_IS_START_OF_PARAGRAPH,
                SentenceDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_SENTENCE_HAS_FOOT_NOTE,
                SentenceDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_SENTENCE_HAS_CROSS_REFERENCE,
                SentenceDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_SENTENCE_CONTENT
        };

        String selection = SentenceDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_SENTENCE_BOOK + "=? AND " 
                + SentenceDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_SENTENCE_CHAPTER + "=?";

        String[] selectionArgs = {book.getShortenedName(), chapter.toString()};

        String orderBy = SentenceDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_SENTENCE_ORDER_NUM + " ASC";

        Cursor cursor = null;
        SQLiteDatabase database = null;

        try {
            database = sentenceDBH.getReadableDatabase();
            cursor = database.query(SentenceDatabaseHelper.TABLE_SENTENCE,
                    columns, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, orderBy);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "There was an error while accessing the database.", e);
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
            if (database != null) {
                database.close();
            }
        }

        int sentenceNumIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(SentenceDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_SENTENCE_NUM);
        int hasFootNoteIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(SentenceDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_SENTENCE_HAS_FOOT_NOTE);
        int hasCrossReferenceIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(SentenceDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_SENTENCE_HAS_CROSS_REFERENCE);
        int isStartOfParagraphIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(SentenceDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_SENTENCE_IS_START_OF_PARAGRAPH);
        int contentIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(SentenceDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_SENTENCE_CONTENT);

        List<ChapterElement> chapterElements = new ArrayList<ChapterElement>( cursor.getCount() );
        while ( cursor.moveToNext() ) {
            int sentenceNum = cursor.getInt(sentenceNumIndex);
            boolean hasFootNote = (cursor.getInt(hasFootNoteIndex) == 1) ? true : false;
            boolean hasCrossRef = (cursor.getInt(hasCrossReferenceIndex) == 1) ? true : false;
            boolean isStartOfParagraph = (cursor.getInt(isStartOfParagraphIndex) == 1) ? true : false;
            String content = cursor.getString(contentIndex);

            ChapterElement chapterElement = new ChapterElement(sentenceNum, hasFootNote, hasCrossRef,
                    isStartOfParagraph, content);
            chapterElements.add(chapterElement);
        }

        cursor.close();
        database.close();

        return chapterElements;
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "unload the application (destroying cache)".  What cache?

Comment: have you checked data immediately after it is retrived from database?

Comment: @Simon After the book chapter has been loaded from the database and parsed, I cache it so I don't have to load it from the DB and parse it again.

Comment: @SyedMuhammadUmair It's difficult to do that, as it's very sporadic and difficult to reproduce. Also, seeing as how after the application is shut down, and re-loaded the sentence will show properly, and the algorithm should produce the same result each time, it seems the database is giving me the reproduction. I'm working on trying to confirm this.

Comment: @Scott.  With respect, if I was to place a bet on such a significant bug in SQLite or a bug in your cache/algorithm, I know where I'd place my money.  I would be logging the cache in/outs and tracing the algorithm.

Comment: @Simon I removed any processing from the text, and the issue persists. I can't get it to happen with a debugger though. I was wondering if maybe it's an issue with the way I'm using the database. I have 2 or 3 threads pulling stuff from the db at times, and I'm wondering if the way I'm using the DB is the problem.

Comment: If you're still having this issue (or for the benefit of others with a similar problem), please post the threading code. Sounds like there's a buffer being overwritten or something similar due to concurrent access.

Comment: Here is a wrapper I wrote/use which makes it slightly easier to use SQLite well in threaded situations, try it out and let me know if your problem still appears - https://github.com/kashifrazzaqui/sqldb